# Wallpaper does not set on lock screen on MIUI 10.2 redmi devices

Tags: java, android, live-wallpaper, android-wallpaper

I am trying to set wallpaper on lock screen in miui 10.2 Redmi devices.

I can set home screen wallpaper using this code :

```
 wallpaperManager.setBitmap(crackedBitmap);
```

But when i am trying to set lock screen wallpaper using this code it's not working :

```
WallpaperManager wallpaperManager;
wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
wallpaperManager.setBitmap(bitmap,null,true,WallpaperManager.FLAG_LOCK);
```

Toast is printing that wallpaper is set but not showing in lock screen

Comment: MIUI does not allow it https://in.c.mi.com/thread-1252992-1-0.html. It seems there is no way you can do it.

Comment: Ok thank you @ShreyGarg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MIUI does not allow it, check [this](http://in.c.mi.com/thread-1252992-1-0.html), [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/Xiaomi/comments/blwnzg/miui_10_cant_change_lockscreen_wallpaper_with/) or [this](http://en.miui.com/thread-3144061-1-1.html).

It seems there is no way you can do it as of now.

Comment: Do you have any code to redirect bitmap to google wallpaper app?

Comment: Nope, a good way is to let user download the image and help him/her open in gallery to set wallpaper